# populate mongoose co-related schema for tree-view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bluebird

I have created following mongoose schema

**workspace-model.js**

```js
var mongoose=require('mongoose')
var uniqueValidator=require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var workspaceSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{type: String, lowercase: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"],
  //match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/, 'is invalid'],
  index: true,
  unique: true
},
  processes:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Process'}],

  },{timestamp:true})

workspaceSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator,{message:'is already taken'});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Workspace',workspaceSchema)
```

**process-model.js**

```js
var mongoose=require('mongoose')
var uniqueValidator=require('mongoose-unique-validator')
var processSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{type: String, lowercase: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"],
  //match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/, 'is invalid'],
  index: true,
  unique: true
},
  state:String, //enabled/disabled/started/stopped/checkin/checkout/starting/stopping
  queues:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Queue'}],
  workspace:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Workspace'}
},{timestamp:true})

processSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator,{message:'is already taken'});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Process',processSchema)
```

**queue-model.js**

```js
var mongoose=require('mongoose')
var uniqueValidator=require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var queueSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{type: String, lowercase: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"],
  //match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/, 'is invalid'],
  index: true,
  unique: true
},
  type:String, //start//end/custom/decision/split/join
  prev:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Queue'},
  next:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Queue'},
  workitems:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Workitem'}],
  process:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Process'}
},{timestamp:true})
queueSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator,{message:'is already taken'});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Queue',queueSchema)
```

**workitem-model.js**

```js
var mongoose=require('mongoose')
var uniqueValidator=require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var workitemSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  status:String, //locked//processing//done//available
  lockedby:String,
  queue:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Queue'},
  process:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Process'}
},{timestamp:true})
//workitemSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator,{message:'is already taken'});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Workitem',workitemSchema)
```

like to populate the data in the following tree-view format

**workspace ->[process]-->[queue]-->[workitem]**

tried following but all sub paths and array items) are not getting populating.

```js
...

var Process=require('./models/process-model')
var Workspace=require('./models/workspace-model')
var Workitem=require('./models/workitem-model')
var Queue=require('./models/queue-model')


Workspace.findOne({name:'dummy'}).populate({
    path: 'processes',
    // Get friends of friends - populate the 'friends' array for every friend
    populate: { path: 'queues' }
  }).exec().then((data)=>{console.log(data})
```

following is sample data file..

```js
workspace

{
  "_id": ObjectId("59f313665087dc2648ab2dc1"),
  "name": "dummy",
  "processes": [
    ObjectId("59f313665087dc2648ab2dc2")
  ],
  "__v": 1
}

process {
  "_id": ObjectId("59f313665087dc2648ab2dc2"),
  "workspace": ObjectId("59f313665087dc2648ab2dc1"),
  "state": "enabled",
  "name": "outward",
  "queues": [
    ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55b"),
    ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55c"),
    ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55d")
  ],
  "__v": 1
}
queue {
  "_id": ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55c"),
  "process": ObjectId("59f313665087dc2648ab2dc2"),
  "type": "custom",
  "name": "data entry",
  "workitems": [],
  "__v": 0,
  "next": ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55d"),
  "prev": ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55b")
} {
  "_id": ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55d"),
  "process": ObjectId("59f313665087dc2648ab2dc2"),
  "type": "end",
  "name": "work exit",
  "workitems": [],
  "__v": 0,
  "prev": ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55c")
} {
  "_id": ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55b"),
  "process": ObjectId("59f313665087dc2648ab2dc2"),
  "type": "start",
  "name": "work introduction",
  "workitems": [
    ObjectId("59f33b3b99506b25f033ecf5")
  ],
  "__v": 1,
  "next": ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55c")
}
workitem {
  "_id": ObjectId("59f33b3b99506b25f033ecf5"),
  "status": "available",
  "__v": 0,
  "process": ObjectId("59f313665087dc2648ab2dc2"),
  "queue": ObjectId("59f3312ee9bbaa27e032f55b")
}
```

Please help .
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the console.log was unable to print after 2-3 nested level.
solution is as follows

```js
var util = require('util')

  .....
//following line will print nested objects
console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null))
  ....
```